# Get all mailboxes with Python exchangelib

Tags: python, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchangelib, mailbox

I'm using Python exchangelib for loading information from Microsoft Exchange. I need to load all mailboxes from Exchange server.

Can I get it with exchangelib?

Answer (score 0):

EWS does not support fetching all accounts on the server. This is an administrative task only available via e.g. PowerShell commands.

You may be lucky that all accounts are available in your GAL. In that case, you can fetch the full list of accounts from there.